# Does facebook graph require the same web host forever?

Tags: url, facebook-graph-api, web-hosting

I'm new to the Facebook Graph, but I appear to be stuck. I have my own domain name, but I have a separate web hosting URL. So I have set up permanent domain forwarding from my domain to the hosted URL. How can I set up facebook to point to the correct URL? If I set facebook to all point to my domain, facebook complains of a circular URL reference.

It works properly if I point facebook to the hosted URL, but then I'm going to be stuck forever with that host. If someday I want to change provider, my understanding is that anyone who Liked one of my pages will lose that like. Please help me understand how I should set this up. Thanks to all.

UPDATE: Sorry I forgot to mention that the domain (blah.com) is at one provider (using GoDaddy), and I'm looking for just one sub-domain (project1.blah.com) to be forwarded to a free web hosting environment (project1.webuda.com) where I set up a facebook graph-based web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with. I didn't realize that I could do this. I set up my DNS so that my web host's nameserver could be specified, but only for a particular subdomain. The web page appears to be working properly now, and I will mark this answer as correct once I confirm that facebook's opengraph is also working properly, when I switch it all over to use my actual domain instead of my web host's domain.

Comment: So the quick answer to my original question is that the domain has to be set up with a nameserver at the host, rather than using domain forwarding.

Comment: Confirmed that the modified DNS configuration works properly with open graph.

Answer (score 1):

your domains are set up incorrectly. you should not have to redirect from your domain to your "hosted URL".

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean? What should I do instead?

Comment: if you have a decent hosting provider, you should be able to point your domain name to the IP address of the server.

it looks like you've found out how to implement this already.

Answer (score 1):

If the URL is forwarded to another URL its not likely that FB will allow the process to continue, security reasons on top of other reasons. If you want to change the URL from your FB app however you would have to go to developers.facebook.com and reassign the URL for your app to one you want to use.

Comment: Ok I must be missing something obvious here. How _should_ this work? I have a domain name, and I have a hosting service. How should I set this up, or how would a _normal_ person set this up?

Comment: Initially going to http://developers.facebook.com signing in with your account and then in the top right I believe you will see an option to add a new app or manage apps. Something to that extent. Where you will walk through options to set up your app from the domain URL that gets the callback information to the name, and all the other rights for the app. Which is where you would plug in the domain you want to be recognized. This domain can not be a "forwarded" or "redirected" domain. The sub domain thing I just noticed however is dependent upon your hosting provider settings.

Comment: you can set up a sub domain through godaddy at domain level, but I believe its forwarded, redirecting all requests from it to whatever. Unless your free host is giving you DNS information to tie that sub domain into.